# What does load resources from Content instead of Resource mean?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to optimize my `Xamarin.Forms` application and watching this video: [Optimizing App Performance with Xamarin.Forms](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RZvdql3Ev0E) it mentioned the following:

[image]

> Load Images from Content instead of Resource

Looking at this link: [Working with Images](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/images/) I can see no mention of loading from **Content** only loading from **Resources**

So my question is what does ***"Load images from Content"*** this mean? and how do I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of embedding images as resources into your assembly, add them as bundled content in your project. They will then be packaged into your app (`.apk` / `.ipa`) as content you can load from the "file system".

i.e. Do not use `Embedded Resource` but `Content`, `Bundle Resource`, `AndroidResouce`, etc... as the build type.

- Content/Local images - displaying images shipped with the application, including resolving native resolutions like iOS Retina or Android high-DPI versions of an image.
- Embedded images - images embedded as an assembly resource.

Comment: Just to clarify. My images are currently in my `Android` project with build action of `AndroidResouce` but you are saying to change the build action to `Content`? are there any negative implications of doing this?

Comment: @user1 That type is fine, they are taking about classic resource embedding into an assembly. An `AndroidResouce` gets bundled as a "file" into your `.apk`

Comment: @user1 Check out @ https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/resources_in_android/

Comment: Thats great. Thanks!